# Python: Redefine function so that it references its own self

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, reference, functional-programming

Say I have got some function `fun`, the actual code body of which is out of my control. I can create a new function which does some preprocessing before calling `fun`, i.e.

```
def process(x):
    x += 1
    return fun(x)
```

If I now want `process` to take the place of `fun` for all future calls to `fun`, I need to do something like

```
# Does not work
fun = process
```

This does not work however, as this creates a cyclic reference problem as now `fun` is called from within the body of `fun`. One solution I have found is to reference a copy of `fun` inside of `process`, like so:

```
# Works
import copy
fun_cp = copy.copy(fun)
def process(x):
    x += 1
    return fun_cp(x)
fun = process
```

but this solution bothers me as I don't really know how Python constructs a copy of a function. I guess my problem is identical to that of extending a class method using inheritance and the `super` function, but here I have no class.

How can I do this properly? I would think that this is a common enough task that some more or less idiomatic solution should exist, but I have had no luck finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is *not* constructing a copy of your function. `copy.copy(fun)` just returns `fun`; the difference is that you saved that to the `fun_cp` variable, a different variable from the one you saved `process` to, so it's still in `fun_cp` when `process` tries to look for it.

I'd do something similar to what you did, saving the original function to a different variable, just without the "copy":

```
original_fun = fun
def fun(x):
    x += 1
    return original_fun(x)
```

If you want to apply the same wrapping to multiple functions, defining a decorator and doing `fun = decorate(fun)` is more reusable, but for a one-off, it's more work than necessary and an extra level of indentation.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a use case for python's closures. Have a function return your function.

```
def getprocess(f):
    def process(x):
        x += 1
        return f(x)  # f is referenced from the enclosing scope.

    return process

myprocess = getprocess(fun) 
myprocess = getprocess(myprocess)
```

Comment: I don't get why you call `getprocess` twice? And surely this does not result in variable named `fun` which when called calls the original `fun` with the given argument plus 1. If I replace the last two lines with `fun = getprocess(fun)` I get what I want, I think. :-)

Comment: @jmd_dk The answer was based on my understanding from the somewhat vague description you've given in the question. I'm not sure if my last two lines adequately captures what you wanted, but I do think closures is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to coldspeed for the idea of using a closure. A fully working and polished solution is

```
import functools

def getprocess(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def process(x):
        x += 1
        return f(x)
    return process

fun = getprocess(fun)
```

Note that this is 100% equivalent to applying a decorator (`getprocess`) to `fun`. I couldn't come up with this solution as the dedicated decorator syntax `@getprocess` can only be used at the definition place of the function (here `fun`). To apply it on an existing function though, just do `fun = getprocess(fun)`.